# 301 redirect htaccess to right URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect `újdonságok-c-1.html` to `ujdonsagok`.

The `.htaccess` file is now:

```
RewriteRule ^újdonságok-c-1.html ujdonsagok [R=301,L]
```

The problem is: the content of ujdonsagok.html appears well, but the URL is the old one, újdonságok-c-1.html

So the content is new but the URL is old.
And also the same time the new ULR arrears with the new content.

What could be the problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "the content of ujdonsagok.html appears well, but the URL is the old one, újdonságok-c-1.html" - That is not what the rule does you've posted. In fact, the rule you've posted it not strictly valid by itself (it is also missing the trailing `.html`). Do you perhaps have another rule that is performing the action you are seeing? What other directives do you have?

Comment: There are no other directives.
And there not .html on the end of new URL's. (Sorry, I  revised it in my question)

Comment: So how is `ujdonsagok.html` being served when you request `ujdonsagok`? This doesn't happen by itself. Are you relying on MultiViews? "no other directives" - not even `RewriteBase`? It's just that your existing rule would result in a malformed redirect by itself - which makes it look like something else is triggering this redirect. The `R=301` flag triggers an external redirect (if this rule is even being processed), so again, it doesn't look like this rule is even being processed??